# Calculating Degrees of Freedom for Each Predictor/Coefficient in Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, degrees-of-freedom

So I'm sure there's likely a simple answer here and I've just been thinking about this question for too long, but would appreciate your help nonetheless! I'm trying to calculate what the degrees of freedom would be for each of the individual predictors/coefficients in a multiple logistic regression model.  When I run the logistic regression in R, I get the overall model's degrees of freedom, but not the individual ones.  What calculation do I need to run for each predictor/coefficient to find their own degrees of freedom?

Is it number of observations within that predictor minus the overall number of parameters for the entire model, or something else?

I'm using this paper (table below) as reference, but can't figure out they calculated their individual DF for each coefficient/predictor:

[image]

Link to their paper here: https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C08A4270B0DC219461466BE9BC6C06AC/S0954394521000235a.pdf/a-variationist-analysis-of-first-person-singular-subject-expression-in-louisiana-french.pdf

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "own degrees of freedom" in this context and why it might interest you?

Comment: Sure! I need to put the results into a table for the paper I'm writing up, all the advice has been to include the DF for each of the coefficients/predictors.  I'm basically copying how the paper in the original question has done it (just added it in), but can't figure out how they've done it.

Comment: It's an interesting question -- but does the answer matter?  And, because the paper unfortunately is behind a paywall, you are really hoping someone here can reverse-engineer the results or guess about the author's methods, whereas consulting the methods section of the paper (or even writing its authors) would be a way to obtain a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

The paper is wrong.  You don't get regression degrees of freedom for an intercept, and you don't get non-integer d.f. with standard unpenalized maximum likelihood estimation.  Regression d.f. are the number of parameters devoted to a predictor.  Also it's not best statistical practice to provide (what should have been) single d.f. tests for a parameter that is part of a group of parameters for a > 2 category categorical predictor.  Multiple d.f. "chunk" tests should have been provided for categorical predictors.  The d.f. there is one less than the number of categories.  A definition of degrees of freedom may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/glossary).

Comment: +1.  But it would be interesting to read educated guesses concerning what the authors actually did.  It's unclear to me whether a "morphological regression model" is some specialized technique or just a fancy name for (mis)applying a standard regression technique to a specific type of data.